# Why does this code give a 'expected primary-expression before ',' token' compile error?

Tags: c++, struct

I am getting the following error message stated in title when compiling and don't know what's wrong. I am trying to pass an array of structs into a function. It is failing with the following error:

> Error message error: expected primary-expression before ',' token

gpio.h

```
#ifndef __GPIO_H__
#define __GPIO_H__

#include <stdint.h>
#include "settings.h"

int open(config *configureGpio, bool *result);

#endif
```

settings.h

```
#ifndef __SETTINGS_H__
#define __SETTINGS_H__

#include <stdint.h>

#define OUTPUT          1
#define INPUT           0
#define HIGH            1
#define LOW             0

struct config
{
    int nPin;
    bool bOut;
    bool bIHigh;
};

config gpioConfig[4] =
{
    {8, OUTPUT, LOW},
    {4, INPUT,  LOW},
    {3, INPUT,  LOW},
    {2, INPUT,  LOW}
};
#endif
```

gpio.cpp

```
#include "gpio.h"

int open(config *configureGpio, bool *res)
{
    return 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "gpio.h"
#include "settings.h"

int main() {
    bool res = false;
    open(config, &res);
}
```

Comment: `&bool` -> `&res`? You should set up proper syntax highlighting and use different naming styles for type names and variable names.

Comment: @VTT typo sorry

Comment: An extra comma after last item `{2, INPUT,  LOW},` is wrong as well... You should use prefix-style command to avoid such problems

Comment: you are passing a pointer to struct not an array of structs.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
open(config, &res);
```

`config` is no variable but a type. You might want to use `gpioConfig` instead.

BTW:
I am not sure if `open` is a good function name as it might collide with [this open function](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open).

Also defining a global array in a header file isn't really good style.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a `data-type` as a parameter but pass the variables. Also when passing arrays be cautious about falling into the `array decaying to pointer`. So you should pass the size as a separate parameter.

So your code can look like this:

```
int open(config *configureGpio, const int size, bool *res){
    for(int i(0); i < size; i++)
        ;// do something
    return 0;
}
```